# Accessing element of AudioIOTensor kills Jupyter Kernel

Tags: tensorflow, audio, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to access an element of a tf io AudioIOTensor. It looks reasonable to my untrained eye during loading.

```
audio_tensor = tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor("my_file.mp3")
<AudioIOTensor: shape=[8084480       2], dtype=<dtype: 'float32'>, rate=44100>
```

When printing element 1, it looks like this

```
audio_tensor[1]
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 0.000000e+00, -3.859234e-16], dtype=float32)>
```

It has 2 values at index 1 and I tried getting the second one

```
audio_tensor[1, 1]
```

and every executed block thereafter, it outputs

> Error: Kernel is dead
> Error: Kernel is dead
> at g._sendKernelShellControl (c:\Users\jonam.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044\out\client\extension.js:52:1006195)
> at g.sendShellMessage (c:\Users\jonam.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044\out\client\extension.js:52:1005964)
> at g.requestExecute (c:\Users\jonam.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044\out\client\extension.js:52:1008506)
> at d.requestExecute (c:\Users\jonam.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044\out\client\extension.js:37:325680)
> at w.requestExecute (c:\Users\jonam.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044\out\client\extension.js:32:18027)
> at w.executeCodeCell (c:\Users\jonam.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044\out\client\extension.js:52:301076)
> at w.execute (c:\Users\jonam.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044\out\client\extension.js:52:300703)
> at w.start (c:\Users\jonam.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044\out\client\extension.js:52:296367)
> at runMicrotasks ()
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> at async t.CellExecutionQueue.executeQueuedCells (c:\Users\jonam.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044\out\client\extension.js:52:311160)
> at async t.CellExecutionQueue.start (c:\Users\jonam.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.2041215044\out\client\extension.js:52:310700)

Why does the kernel die instead of returning -3.859234e-16?

I'm using Python 3.9.6, tensorflow_io 0.21.0, jupyter notebook 6.2.0 (as best as I can tell) and it's all running in vs code, if that makes any difference.

Any help would be appreciated, have a nice day :)